# HTTPSEverywhere bug? (forcing onions)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, onion-services, https

http://www.kkkkkkkkkk63ava6.onion/wiki/Forcing_.onion_on_Whonix.org

Also "Idea 2" in this post: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/cooking-onions-names-your-onions

This function of httpseverywhere no longer seems to work. When I navigate to whonix.org, the browser takes me to whonix.org -- not www.kkkkkkkkkk63ava6.onion as instructed by the xml. This has been true since about v7.0.2/3. I'm using TBB v7.0.4 currently in Debian with no custom/additional modifications to the browser.

Can someone try replicating and/or possibly report it to the TBB/Httpseverywhere devs? I wouldn't even know where to properly report something like this -- other than here.

Comment: Anyone? Anything? Is anyone else experiencing this bug?